# Error with controller rendering - "does not implement IController"

Tags: mvc

Using Sitecore 8.2

I have multiple MVC projects in a VS Solution. For each project, I remove the *RouteConfig.cs*, but for one, I forgot and clicked on publish. (I'm not sure if thats the reason for the error).

Now the page thows this error -

> The controller for path '/en/home' was not found or does not implement
>   IController.

I removed the *RouteConfig.cs* and published again but no luck. Also, none of the MVC projects have Global.asax included.

I also tried giving the full path in controller rendering.

```
Controller: Sitecore.Feature.Teasers.Controllers.TeasersController, Sitecore.Feature.Teasers  
Controller Action: RenderTeaser
```

**TeasersController.cs**

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.Teasers.Controllers
{
    public class TeasersController : SitecoreController
    {
        // GET: Teasers
        public ActionResult RenderTeaser()
        {
            IEnumerable<Item> teasers = GetTeasers();
            return View("~/Views/Teasers/Teasers.cshtml", teasers);
        }        
    }
}
```

How can I fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Is it the only controller rendering on the page? Are other controller renderings working as expected? From the same assembly are other controller renderings working as expected?

Comment: Try doing a full-text search in your solution to check if `MapRoute(` is used anywhere. When you find it, remove it, then do a full rebuild of your solution and redeploy it.

Comment: Try inheriting TeaserController by System.Web.Mvc.Controller  instead of SitecoreController

Comment: Do you only get this error on the page with this controller rendering or any page?

Answer (score 5):

You need to inherit from `Controller`, not `SitecoreController`.

`SitecoreController` is Sitecore's own controller  (duh, hehe) used for Sitecore's View Rendering components - but is not the one you are meant to inherit from for your own Controller Rendering components.

See also: [How To Make Sitecore Use a MVC Controller, Controller Renderings Explained](http://jondjones.com/how-to-make-sitecore-use-a-mvc-controller-controller-renderings-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

For other still seeing this issue, here is one more scenario:
In my case I was seeing various DLL issues, so I decided to replace bin of my project with an bin of new instance. Then saw this error.
Clean and built my project and then published the code from Visual studio. Everything then started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the dlls are in the temporary cache. Simply try an IIS recycle or reset. And check.

Comment: That did not work:(